# Customer Action "Extend To Vendor"

Tags: acumatica

Using the latest version of Acumatica 5 with the latest and greatest updates, I’m running into a Web API issue that I have not been able to solve. I have code to execute the “Extend To Vendor” action on the Customer screen. It seems to run fine and does not error out but it fails to create the vendor. It seems to me that when performing the same actions through the website interface, the issue is that I’m not sending the correct command to choose the “Yes” button on the popup Warning box “Please confirm if you want to update current Vendor settings with the Vendor Class defaults. Original settings will be perserved otherwise.” I could be totally off though and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
String customerId = "SomeCustomerId";
String vendorClass = “SomeVendorClass”;

AcumaticaApiWS.AR303000Content AR303000 = context.AR303000GetSchema();
AcumaticaApiWS.AP303000Content AP303000 = context.AP303000GetSchema();

context.AR303000Clear();
AR303000.Actions.ExtendToVendor.Commit = true;

AcumaticaApiWS.AR303000Content[] AR303000result = context.AR303000Submit
(
    new AcumaticaApiWS.Command[]
    {
        new AcumaticaApiWS.Value { Value = customerId, LinkedCommand = AR303000.CustomerSummary.CustomerID },
        AR303000.Actions.ExtendToVendor
    }   
);

AcumaticaApiWS.AP303000Content[] AP303000result = context.AP303000Submit
(
    new AcumaticaApiWS.Command[]
    {
        new AcumaticaApiWS.Value { Value = vendorClass, LinkedCommand = AP303000.GeneralInfoFinancialSettings.VendorClass },
        new AcumaticaApiWS.Value { Value = "YES", LinkedCommand = AP303000.GeneralInfoFinancialSettings.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer, Commit = true },
        AP303000.Actions.Save
    }
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. This is not an easy scenario since it involves multiple screens and dialogs, two things which are not trivial to use. The issues in your code sample are:

- The dialog answer has to be set **before** the value. In your case, you're setting the vendor class first. This is counter-intuitive but the system has to know it before the dialog is displayed
- The dialog answer is "Yes", and not "YES". You can see this by using the web browser inspector window and looking at the button title. The text is displayed in uppercase due to CSS styling.
- You need to set the dialog answer on the primary view of the form (`AP303000.VendorSummary.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer`), where the dialog is being displayed. There's no way to know this without looking at the source code, but I believe this is generally the case with dialog boxes.
- The different `Commit = true` settings are not necessary (but don't hurt in this case).

This is the code I used, and in my case it extends a customer to a vendor and changes the vendor class at the same time:

```
String customerId = "ACTIVESTAF";
String vendorClass = "DATACENTER";

AcumaticaApiWS.AR303000Content AR303000 = context.AR303000GetSchema();
AcumaticaApiWS.AP303000Content AP303000 = context.AP303000GetSchema();

context.AR303000Clear();

AcumaticaApiWS.AR303000Content[] AR303000result = context.AR303000Submit
(
    new AcumaticaApiWS.Command[]
    {
        new AcumaticaApiWS.Value { Value = customerId, LinkedCommand = AR303000.CustomerSummary.CustomerID },
        AR303000.Actions.ExtendToVendor
    }
);

AcumaticaApiWS.AP303000Content[] AP303000result = context.AP303000Submit
(
    new AcumaticaApiWS.Command[]
    {
        new AcumaticaApiWS.Value { Value = "Yes", LinkedCommand = AP303000.VendorSummary.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer },
        new AcumaticaApiWS.Value { Value = vendorClass, LinkedCommand = AP303000.GeneralInfoFinancialSettings.VendorClass },
        AP303000.Actions.Save
    }
);
```

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy what do you mean? That this should be included in T900?

Comment: T900 ACUMATICA WEB SERVICES. I mean how to make import/export operations for cases if pop up appears.

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy we're currently redoing the web services training, will share.